# Under what conditions will `RealProxy.GetTransparentProxy()` return `null`?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy-classes, realproxy

The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.gettransparentproxy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx doesn't indicate a scenario where `GetTransparentProxy` will return `null`, but I'm getting a `null` back when I call it.

What circumstances will cause this behavior?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it. Its *critical* to have your `RealProxy` derived class call the base constructor with the type to be proxied. In my case:

```
public class MyProxy<T> : RealProxy
{
    public MyProxy()
        : base(typeof(T))    // this was missing
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I just hit into this issue all over again today. Note to anyone else with this issue -- Microsoft .NET returns null, but Mono throws an exception.